# Make Xdebug ignore multiple requests

Tags: javascript, php, xdebug, xdebug-3

I have several places in my app where I call an API endpoint every 60 seconds.

When I try to debug with Xdebug the controller that is associated to that endpoint it often takes me more than a minute while I think/step over and so on, so I end up getting another request that Xdebug intercepts at the same previous breakpoint (I get two lines highlighted and actually when I step over again it will start from the new request onwards).

Is there a way to tell Xdebug to temporarilly ignore future requests being intercepted by Xdebug? Of course I could comment the JS part where I do the setTimeout to call again to the same endpoint but I would like to know if there's an alternative that doesn't imply tinkering with my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version (1.21.0) of VS Code PHP Debug adapter supports this via the `maxConnections` `launch.json` setting.

Example showing max 2 parallel connections allowed. If logging is enabled, a line will be printed if a new connection is rejected.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "maxConnections": 2,
      "log": true
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this on the Xdebug side, but:

If you are using PhpStorm, you can set the "Max. Simultaneous Connections" setting to `1`. It is (in my version) under "PHP", "Debug", "External Connections".

Comment: Thank you, Derick. Is there anything alike for VSCode?

Comment: I don't think so. I've asked the plugin's author.

Comment: There is an open issue for this, but I have not yet gotten to it. Upvote if you need this so I can prioritize. https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/571